# Conflicting buttons with jquery .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

HTML

```
<form id="create-template" class="form" action="" method="post">
    <p class="_50">
        <label for="t-name">Template name</label>
        <input type="text" name="t-name" class="required"/>
    </p>
    <p class="_100">
        <label for="t-html">Template HTML</label>
        <textarea id="t-html" name="t-html" class="required" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
    </p>
    <div class="block-actions">
        <ul class="actions-left">
            <li><a class="button red" id="reset-template" href="javascript:void(0);">Clear</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="actions-right">
            <li><div id="preview"><input type="submit" class="button" value="Preview template"></div></li>
            <li><input type="submit" class="button" value="Create template"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#preview").click(function() {
        $('#create-template').submit(function() {
            window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
            this.target = 'formpopup';
        });
    });
```

When pressing `Preview template` it opens a popup window and will display a preview of the template. This is correct.

After previewing the template, when pressing `Create template` the page submits to the pop up. This is incorrect.

This problem only happens when previewing the template. `Create template` submits the form on the same page unless you preview the template.

How can I keep the `preview template` from conflicting with `create template`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is telling the form to submit to the popup window:

```
this.target = 'formpopup';
```

Change it to:

```
this.target = window.opener;
```

You'll probably want to close the popup after submitting. To do that, add this line:

```
formpopup.close();
```

Comment: When I remove it or rename it to `top` the popup becomes blank. Using `top` A new window opens too. :|

Comment: Thank you for trying, unfortunately it still didn't function as imagined.  I'm sorry it didn't work.

Comment: I am going to post the results to a new window instead of popups.  You are the only one trying to help so I gave you the accepted answer, thank you! :D